# Include into php array only the values surrounded by same specific symbols

Tags: php, arrays

I have a folder with filenames like `-abc-de.php`, `-bcd-ef.php`, `-cd-efg.php` and say `index.php`.

I need to feel my array only with file names which contain symbols surrounded by `-`, may be even limit the number of those symbols strictly to 3, just in case. And truncate their names to those 3 symbols surrounded by `-`.

In other words I need my array to look like `Array ( [0] => abc [1] => bcd )`.

My partly working solution is the following:

```
$array = scandir('folder');
foreach($array as $key => $val){
    $array[$key] = substr($val,1,3);
}
```

It does the job but also includes `cd-` and `nde` which I definitely do not need in my array.

Please help me to make my array exactly as I want it to be.

------- UPDATE -------

With great help of [@AbraCadaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2844319/abracadaver) I've finally made the following code that seems to be what I need:

```
$array = scandir('folder');
$array = preg_grep('/-([a-z]{3})-/', $array);
foreach($array as $key => $val){
    if(preg_match('/-([a-z]{3})-/', $val, $match)) {
        $array[$key] = $match[1];
    }
}
```

I could understand @AbraCadaver wrongly and made something different from what was originally suggested. But it does exactly what I needed.

One more question though:

```
$array = scandir('folder');
foreach($array as $key => $val){
    if(preg_grep('/-([a-z]{3})-/', $val, $match)) {
        $array[$key] = $match[1];
    }
}
```

Why the above construction doesn't work?

Comment: Does the first `-` need to be at the start of the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match `-` and 3 letters and then `-` and store the letters in `$match[1]`.  Do this in the loop:

```
if(preg_match('/-([a-z]{3})-/', $val, $match)) {
    $array[$key] = $match[1];
}
```

To get uppercase and lowercase use the `i` modifier:

```
/-([a-z]{3})-/i
```

To force the match to start at the beginning of the string use the `^` anchor:

```
/^-([a-z]{3})-/i
```

Use any combination.  You can change `a-z` to `a-z0-9` for letters and numbers for example.

Another option would be:

```
$files = glob('folder/-???-*');
```

Or some variation, and then your `substr` will get the characters you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out any value if a string has a - in it

```
$newArray = array_filter($array, fn($string) => strpos($string, '-' === false));
```

Comment: Unfortunately returns an error. Can't say which exactly as I can see only the empty browser screen when this string is used.